# Solspace: Calendar & Tags

Tags: solspace, tags, calendar

I have both Solspace calendar & tag plugin and I trying to create a page that lists all calendar entries that have a particular tag. I have the calendar event with a tag field but when i try and search for them i get everything.

any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Pls post up some simplified code you're using to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go about it is to use the `{exp:tag:entries}` tag to get a list of entry_id's to feed to the `{exp:calendar:events}` tag.

i. e.

```
{exp:calendar:events
event_id="{exp:tag:entries tag="{segment_3}" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{exp:tag:entries}"
}
{title}
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

or something like that.
Versions of EE, Tag, and Calendar?

Comment: thanks for the code example i finally had a chance to get back to this, but the code still returns all the entries.
{exp:calendar:events calendar_id="12329" date_range_start="today" show_months="12" dynamic="off" status="open" orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc" event_id="{exp:tag:entries tag="{last_segment}" inclusive="no" tag_group_name="calTags"}{entry_id}{/exp:tag:entries}"}

Comment: Sorry should have included this info: ExpressionEngine v2.9.2, Calendar 1.8.14, Tag 4.2.9